# Objective-C equivalent of 'tuple unpacking'

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes, I get sad when I can't use Python. In Python, I handle an array of arguments, unpacking them as such:

```
name, handle, parent_handle, [left, top, right, bottom], showing, scrollable = data
```

I must now do the same in Objective-C, with `NSArray`s. Am I doomed to 11 lines of:

```
NSString *name = (NSString *)[data objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *handle = (NSNumber *)[data objectAtIndex:1];
//....
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: @mit3z: indeed, initially it was a dictionary, except this is sent over the network, the arguments are always in this order, and it's much more compact this way without having to specify the keys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  You are doomed.  **DOOMED!**  Mwah ha ha ha ha!

You can omit the casts and use subscripting to make it a little bit shorter though:

```
NSString *name = data[0];
NSNumber *handle = data[1];
// ...
```

You can omit the casts because both `objectAtIndex:` and subscripting return type `id`, which can be converted to any Objective-C class type without casting.